# Substr function not working with IF statement

Tags: perl

I am reading a file with various length strings that i must cut at various start and end positions (left to right). Sometimes the start position is larger than the end position which tells me to cut the string from right to left.

I have the following code. If $start is larger than $end, it will not create the substring. The substr function only works if $end is larger than $start. Not sure why this is happening. 
If I remove the IF/ELSE statement the substr works fine even if $start is larger than $end. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 $start = 20;
 $end = 10;
 $len = 5
 $string = "THISISALONGSTRINGTHATWILLNOTSPLICEUNLESSIREMOVETHEIFSTATEMENT";

 if ($start > $end){
   my $slice = substr($string, $end, $len);
 }
 else{
   my $slice = substr($string, $start, $len);
 }
```

Comment: What is your *expected* output?

Comment: I hope the missing semicolon behind `$len = 5` is just a copy/paste error.

Answer (score 2):

```
my $slice;
if ($start > $end){
  $slice = substr($string, $end, $len);
}
else{
  $slice = substr($string, $start, $len);
}
```

or perhaps

```
my $slice = ($start > $end) 
  ? substr($string, $end, $len) 
  : substr($string, $start, $len);
```

Comment: Declaring $slice outside the IF/ELSE block does not resolve it.

Comment: @user2674514 can you give examples of what is your expected output?

Comment: That seems to work. However, there are other things that I need to do besides the substr if $start > $end. For instance, if $start > $end, I also need to reverse the string. How would I implement your syntax to allow me to do other things to $slice if the condition is met?

Comment: @user2674514 `? reverse substr($string, $end, $len)`

Answer (score 2):

The `my $slice` seems to be wrong, it will go out of scope at the next `}` which means `$slice` won't be set after the `if/else` condition. Put a `my $slice;` in front of the `if` and remove the `my` in the `substr` statements.

Edit: What mpapec says, he was faster than me.

Answer (score 0):

In modern Perl, most variables are *lexically scoped*. This means that they will go in and out of definition depending where  they're defined. Variables defined inside of a *block* will no longer be defined once outside of that block. Think of a block as a pair of curly braces. So, your `if` statement is a block:

```
if ( ... )  {  # Beginning of a block
    ....
    ....
}              # End of a block
```

This means any variable defined (via `my`) in this block will no longer be defined outside of that `if` statement.

To get around this, define your variable *outside* of the if statement, and then change the value:

```
my $slice;          # Variable is defined here
if ( $start > $end ) {
    $slice = substr($string, $end, $len);
}
else {
    $slice = substr($string, $start, $len);
}
say $slice;         # Variable is still set here.
```